# explain this prime number program [C]

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n;

    int a,b,flag=1;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(a=2; a<=n; a++)
    {
        if(n % a == 0)
        {
            printf("not prime");
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag == 1)
    {
        printf("is prime");
    }

    getch();
}
```

when you use this for loop

```
for(a=2; a<=n; a++)
```

when user will input 2 it will print "not prime:

if you put that `if(flag == 1)` statement inside the for loop it doesn't print anything when the user inputs 2. Why is that `if(flag == 1)` outside that for loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i, num, flag = 1;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(i=2; i<=sqrt(num); i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            printf("not prime");
            flag=0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag==1)
    {
        printf("is prime");
    }

    getch();
}
```

when you will use square root in for loop

```
for(i=2; i<=sqrt(num); i++)
```

then it give correct result
if you enter 2 then it prints 2 is prime number
WHY ?

and what is flag variable  how does it work ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this line is wrong:

```
for(a=2; a<=n; a++)
```

It should be this:

```
for(a=2; a<n; a++)
```

Because n is always divisible by itself it will mean that `n % a == 0` when a is n. This does *not* mean the number is not prime. A prime is exactly divisible by 1 and itself, but no other integer.

When you change the test to `a <= sqrt(num)` you also happen to fix this bug.

Comment: I'd call it wrong too. It will result in every number being judged as "not prime".

Comment: Except for calculating the square root on every iteration.  That should be lifted out of the loop.

Comment: @IronMensan: Well you could micro-optimize that... or you could just use a completely different algorithm that's much faster!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(a=2; a <= n; a++)
```

should be

```
for(a=2; a < n; a++)
         //^ difference
```

Also, when you use `sqrt(n)`, you better write this outside the loop to improve performance:

```
int m = sqrt(n); //store the result in int type
for(a=2; a <= m ; a++)
```

In this way, you calculate `sqrt(n)` just ONCE, instead of in every iteration, and instead of relying on the compiler to optimize this step.

Comment: any optimizing compiler worth its name will catch that.

Comment: "worth its name", eh? Neither Clang 1.1 -O3 -S nor GCC 4.3.3 -O3 -S lift the computation of `sqrt` outside the loop. Interestingly, GCC lifts the prerequisite int to double conversion outside the loop. For what it's worth, I find the version with `int m = sqrt(n);` more readable, because it makes it clear that the bound is constant, and because suboptimal code makes me cringe (even when it should be optimized. I don't know if this one should be. It isn't by the compilers I use, for sure)